# How to optimize Firestore Caching and Querymodeling

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a Moneymanagement-App where the user can create Transfers for each day.

I am currently listing all the data on the mainscreen. At the moment that doesn't matter because there isn't much data but imagine a user who uses the app several years and tracking all his spendings.

My first thought was to cache all the available Data for that user but that would cause too many unnecessary reads because the user most likely won't need the data from lets say 5 years ago.

So I thought the solution would be to just implement pagination for that screen.

But :

The user can get statistics about his spendinghistory on another screen by selecting a category and a timeperiod. 
Currently i am running a query on those parameters each time they change but this will obviously also lead to a lot of unnecessary reads.

So the problem is, if the user chooses to get statistics from 5 years ago, that Data wouldn't exist in the cache so i would still have to run a query for this time period and then end up with a incomplete cache of that period because i only got some of the Data based on the Query.

Would love to hear your thoughts on this. How would you handle it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general: don't run aggregation queries from the client on demand. Instead store aggregated data in the database, and update it as data is written.

So say that you keep some annual totals, such as their balance at the start and end of the year, their total income and spend for that year, probably broken down by categories. That is all information that you could put in a document for each year.

You'd have a structure `/users/$uid/totals/$year` and you then have the totals in fields in that document. Every time you write a new transaction, you update the totals document for that user for the current year.

If you do this, you'll only need to read the totals document to show totals, and you'll only need to read individual transactions if you want to show individual transactions.

Also see: [Is it possible to run aggregation queries in Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58614592/is-it-possible-to-run-aggregation-queries-in-firestore/58614687#58614687)

Comment: Okay thanks, let me see if i get this right. For example if the user wants to get statistics about 1 year and 3 months, i would only have this one document for that year, and then query for the other 3 months individually ? 

What would you say to creating these totals also for months or even weeks ? That would create some more writes but may save additional reads.

Comment: That's one way. But you could also write monthly/quarterly aggregation docs. And indeed the whole point here is to make reads easier/cheaper, by making the writes more complex/expensive. So this only works in a scenario where reads far outscale the writes, which is what NoSQL are mostly focused on.

Comment: Okay thanks, i have one more question about this 

I want to break down the data based on the selected period and category. At the moment i am thinking about for example : If the period is > 1 month and < 6 months, show weekly data, if it is > 6 months, show monthly data and so on. That would mean that i still had to store data for each week in the totals of a month, because otherwise i can't breakt the data down. 

I also want to be able to compare positions to another. For example if you select the category groceries, you can compare store x to store y. 

What is your opinion on that ?

Comment: With NoSQL databases you'll need to store the data in a way that fits all your use-cases. As you uncover/describe more use-cases that means you'll need to expand/adapt your data model to allow those use-cases. Instead of covering each use-case, follow the same guidance as before: store data in a format you can more easily/cheaply read, as you see best fit, and modify as you uncover more.

Comment: I also recommend reading: [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/), and watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s), and [Getting to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video) (the last one is for Firestore, but much of its general advice applies to all NoSQL databases).

Comment: Okay, i will check out your resources. Thanks for the detailed explanation !